# SEGFAULT when using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr, double-free

I'm trying to implement the **Lazy Concurrent List-based Set** in C++ by using `shared_ptr`. My reasoning is that `unreachable nodes` will be automatically freed by the last `shared_ptr`. As per my understanding, increment and decrement operation on a `shared_ptr's reference count` is atomic. Which means only the **last shared_ptr** with reference to the node should call **delete/free** for that node. I ran the program for **multiple threads**, but my program is crashing with the error `double free called` or just **Segmentation Fault(SIGSEGV)**. I don't understand how this is possible. Given below is my code for the implementation, with the method names signifying their intended operation.

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<mutex>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

class Thread
{
   public:
      std::thread t;  
};
int n=50,ki=100,kd=100,kc=100;`/*no of threads, no of inserts,deletes & searches*/`


class Node
{
public:
      int key;
      shared_ptr<Node> next;
      bool marked;
      std::mutex nodeLock;

      Node() {
         key=0;
         next = nullptr;
         marked = false;
      }

      Node(int k) {
         key = k;
         next = nullptr;
         marked = false;
      }

      void lock() {
         nodeLock.lock();
      }

      void unlock() {
         nodeLock.unlock();
      }

      ~Node()
      {
      }
};

class List {
   shared_ptr<Node> head;
   shared_ptr<Node> tail;

public:

   bool validate(shared_ptr<Node> pred, shared_ptr<Node> curr) {
      return !(pred->marked) && !(curr->marked) && ((pred->next) == curr);
   }

   List() {
      head=make_shared<Node>(INT_MIN);
      tail=make_shared<Node>(INT_MAX);
      head->next=tail;
   }

   bool add(int key)
   {
      while(true)
      {
         /*shared_ptr<Node> pred = head;
         shared_ptr<Node> curr = pred->next;*/
        auto pred = head;
        auto curr = pred->next;

         while (key>(curr->key))
         {
            pred = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
         }

         pred->lock();
         curr->lock();

         if (validate(pred,curr))
         {
            if (curr->key == key)
            {
               curr->unlock();
               pred->unlock();
               return false;
            }
            else
            {
                shared_ptr<Node> newNode(new Node(key));
               //auto newNode = make_shared<Node>(key);
                //shared_ptr<Node> newNode = make_shared<Node>(key);
                newNode->next = curr;
                pred->next = newNode;
                curr->unlock();
                pred->unlock();
                return true;
            }
         }
         curr->unlock();
         pred->unlock();
      }
   }

   bool remove(int key)
   {
      while(true)
      {
         /*shared_ptr<Node> pred = head;
         shared_ptr<Node> curr = pred->next;*/

        auto pred = head;
        auto curr = pred->next;

         while (key>(curr->key))
         {
            pred = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
         }

         pred->lock();
         curr->lock();

         if (validate(pred,curr))
         {
            if (curr->key != key)
            {
               curr->unlock();
               pred->unlock();
               return false;
            }
            else
            {
               curr->marked = true;
               pred->next = curr->next;
               curr->unlock();
               pred->unlock();
               return true;
            }
         }
         curr->unlock();
         pred->unlock();
      }
   }

   bool contains(int key) {
      //shared_ptr<Node> curr = head->next;
    auto curr = head->next;

      while (key>(curr->key)) {
         curr = curr->next;
      }
      return curr->key == key && !curr->marked;
   }
}list;

void test(int curr)
{
   bool test;
    int time;

    int val, choice;
    int total,k=0;
    total=ki+kd+kc;

    int i=0,d=0,c=0;

    while(k<total)
    {
        choice = (rand()%3)+1;

        if(choice==1)
        {
            if(i<ki)
            {
                val = (rand()%99)+1;
                test = list.add(val);
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            if(d<kd)
            {
                val = (rand()%99)+1;
                test = list.remove(val);
                d++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        else if(choice==3)
        {
            if(c<kc)
            {
                val = (rand()%99)+1;
                test = list.contains(val);
                c++;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
   int i;

   vector<Thread>thr(n);

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      thr[i].t = thread(test,i+1);
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      thr[i].t.join();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I'm not able to figure out what's wrong with the above code. The errors differ every time, some of which are just `SEGFAULTS` or

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong in the above code? And how to fix that error?
**EDIT:** Added a very crude `test function` which randomly calls the three `list methods`. Also, number of threads and number of each operations are declared globally. Crude programming, but it recreates the **SEGFAULT**.

Comment: As for using `shared_ptr` for this, cool. I salute experimentation.

Comment: @user4581301, should I open another question with the full code including `main`? Or just post it in comments?

Comment: @DeeJay Edit your current post with the `main` function.  There is no need to start another question.  Also do not post code in the comments.

Comment: @user4581301, No, but that's the main idea behind this list. Once you lock `pred & curr`, the 'validate` function is called to detect any **synchronization conflict**. `validate` checks if `pred & curr` have not been marked and **pred is still pointing to curr**. Even if `pred` or `curr` are deleted, they'd be marked first(**remove method**). Hence **Lazy Synchronization** is the List's name.

Comment: @user4581301 added the necessary code edits.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie added the necessary code edits.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that you're not using the atomic store and load operations for your `shared_ptr`s.

It is true that the reference count in the control block (to which each `shared_ptr` participating in ownership of a particular shared object has a pointer to) of a `shared_ptr` is atomic, however, the data members of the `shared_ptr` itself aren't.

Thus it is safe to have multiple threads each with their own `shared_ptr` to a shared object, but it is not save to have multiple threads access the same `shared_ptr` as soon as at least one of them is using a non-const member function, which is what you're doing when reassigning the `next` pointer.

#### Illustrating the problem

Let's look at a the (simplified and prettified) copy-constructor of libstdc++'s `shared_ptr` implementation:

```
shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& rhs)
 : m_ptr(rhs.m_ptr),
   m_refcount(rhs.m_refcount) 
{ }
```

Here `m_ptr` is just a raw pointer to the shared object, and `m_refcount` is a class that does the reference counting and also handles eventual deletion of the object `m_ptr` points to.

Just one example of what can go wrong: Assume that currently a thread is trying to figure out whether a particular key is contained in the list. It starts with the copy-initialization `auto curr = head->next` in `List::contains`. Just after it managed to initialize `curr.m_ptr` the OS scheduler decides this thread has to pause and schedules in another thread.

That other thread is removing the successor of `head`. Since the ref-count of `head->next` still is 1 (after all, the ref-count of `head->next` wasn't modified by thread 1 yet), when the second thread is done removing the node it is being deleted.

Then some time later the first thread continues. It completes the initialization of `curr`, but since `m_ptr` was already initialized before thread 2 started the deletion, it still points to the now deleted node. When trying to compare `key > curr->key` thread 1 will access invalid memory.

#### Using std::atomic_load and std::atomic_store to prevent the issue

`std::atomic_load` and `std::atomic_store` prevent the issue from occurring by locking a mutex before the call to the copy-constructor/copy-assignment-operator of the `shared_ptr` that is passed in by pointer. If all reads from and writes to `shared_ptr`s that are shared across multiple threads are through `std::atomic_load`/`std::atomic_store` resp. it can never happen that one thread has only modified `m_ptr` but not the reference count at the time another thread starts reading or modifying the same `shared_ptr`.

With the necessary atomic loads and stores the `List` member functions should read as follows:

```
bool validate(Node const& pred, Node const& curr) {
   return !(pred.marked) && !(curr.marked) && 
          (std::atomic_load(&pred.next).get() == &curr);
}

bool add(int key) {
    while (true) {
        auto pred = std::atomic_load(&head);
        auto curr = std::atomic_load(&pred->next);

        while (key > (curr->key)) {
            pred = std::move(curr);
            curr = std::atomic_load(&pred->next);
        }

        std::scoped_lock lock{pred->nodeLock, curr->nodeLock};
        if (validate(*pred, *curr)) {
            if (curr->key == key) {
                return false;
            } else {
                auto new_node = std::make_shared<Node>(key);

                new_node->next = std::move(curr);
                std::atomic_store(&pred->next, std::move(new_node));
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool remove(int key) {
    while (true) {
        auto pred = std::atomic_load(&head);
        auto curr = std::atomic_load(&pred->next);

        while (key > (curr->key)) {
            pred = std::move(curr);
            curr = std::atomic_load(&pred->next);
        }

        std::scoped_lock lock{pred->nodeLock, curr->nodeLock};
        if (validate(*pred, *curr)) {
            if (curr->key != key) {
                return false;
            } else {
                curr->marked = true;
                std::atomic_store(&pred->next, std::atomic_load(&curr->next));
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool contains(int key) {
    auto curr = std::atomic_load(&head->next);

    while (key > (curr->key)) {
        curr = std::atomic_load(&curr->next);
    }
    return curr->key == key && !curr->marked;
}
```

Additionally, you should also make `Node::marked` a `std::atomic_bool`.

Comment: Okay.... My reasoning was, the moment(instant) a thread discovers an object(using **shared_ptr** ), the **reference count** would be incremented atomically. I assumed that both the above steps i.e. **reading the next pointer** and **ref_count increment** , would be one atomic step. So, no thread would be able to free a node, if another thread gains a reference(reads the next pointer) first.

Comment: @DeeJay The issue is that creating a copy of a `shared_ptr` always needs to do at least two things: Increment the reference count in the control block and then copy the pointer to the control block. Assume that the reference count is modified first. Then you can have the following scenario: One thread is about to reassign a `next` ptr. It has already decremented the reference count of the old object and noticed that the reference count is zero. Before actually deleting the object that thread is scheduled out.

Comment: Another thread comes along and now copies that `shared_ptr`. So it goes ahead and increments the reference count and copies the pointer to the control block. Then the first thread resumes and deletes the pointee and possibly also the control block and replaces it by the new pointee and control block. In any case, the copy of the `shared_ptr` of the second thread now points to an already free'd location of memory.

Comment: So, how does using `atomics` solves this problem? Looks like I have to read about `atomic` and `shared_ptr` in more depth.

Comment: @DeeJay `std::atomic_load` and `std::atomic_store` lock a mutex so that while an `atomic_load` is in progress there can't be a simultaneous `atomic_store` to (or another `std::atomic_load` from)  the same `shared_ptr`.

Comment: could you please elaborate this statement? **the reference count in the control block of a shared_ptr is atomic, however, the data members of the shared_ptr itself aren't**

Comment: @DeeJay I've extended my answer to show the issue with an example run of two threads.

Comment: Does this require C++17 support? Because I'm getting a lot of errors from this code. `no matching function for call to ‘atomic_load(const std::shared_ptr<Node>*)`

Comment: @DeeJay: The only C++17 features I've used are std::scoped_lock (as a replacement for the manual calls to `Node::lock` and `Node::unlock`) as well as constructor template argument deduction for the `std::scoped_lock`s. But `std::atomic_load` and `std::atomic_store` are C++11 features.

Comment: Okay, but `atomic_load` and `atomic_store` are not working with `shared_ptr`. I'm using **g++ 4.9.4 and C++11** , but I'm getting the following error: `no matching function for call to ‘atomic_load(const std::shared_ptr<Node>*) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164981/discussion-between-dee-jay-and-corristo).

Comment: @DeeJay Apparently libstdc++ didn't fully implement C++11's STL until GCC 5.1. But with that I was able to get it to run after replacing every `std::scoped_lock` by two `std::lock_guard`s. You can see the result [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WSd2xuDIGZ7xHjBU). However, note that I had to decrease the number of threads to 20 as otherwise wandbox runs out of resources. You can of course easily copy/paste the code and test it yourself with the original number of threads.

Comment: Okay. The code worked for me after I removed scoped_lock and did the locking and unlocking manually. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Corristo Smart pointers have nothing to do with the "Standard Template Library".

Comment: @curiousguy What are you referring to? I haven't talked about general smart pointers anywhere, neither in my answer nor the comments.

Comment: @Corristo Replying to your comment "_Apparently libstdc++ didn't fully implement C++11's STL until GCC 5.1_"...